# Entropy in Pandas returning '-inf' (infinity)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, entropy

I am calculating entropy of a data frame "default of credit card clients". I took it from the UCI Machine Learning Repository. https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/default+of+credit+card+clients

CSV file available here - https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/default-of-credit-card-clients-dataset

I used  the following code

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
entropy(df)
```

This is my output:

```
array([10.11582214, 10.01808774, 10.25940955, 10.22181775, 10.25018627,
       10.27641471,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf,
              -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf,        -inf,
              -inf,        -inf,        -inf,  9.15542383,  8.98160775,
        8.97607359,  8.94236069,  8.94899185,  8.81999977,  8.80026465])
```

Can Entropy, by definition, become infinite? I've googled https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_handle_entropy_with_infinite_value

However, I need experts advice on why entropy is infinite and **how to rectify this in pandas.**

**Note - At least '0' should come in the place of '-inf'.**

Comment: it looks like you're calculating entropy on non-probability values. Can you show what is in `df`?

Comment: Its computed as `-sum(pk * log(pk), axis=0).`. `-inf` is indicating that you have zeroes or negative values there, so when taking the natural log you're hitting an assymptote

Comment: @yatu it would return nan in case of zeroes:  `pk * log(pk) = 0 * -inf = nan`

Comment: Good point @marat

Comment: Thanks for commenting - its because the df contains negative numbers (just like @julian answered) yet, any ideas how to calculate entropy here? any workarounds?

Comment: Just add the minimum to all data samples to ensure they are positive @SabariVishnuJayanthanJ (you're transforming equally all data so you're not modifying the entropy)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting @yatu. I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your df possibly contains negative numbers.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import entropy

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,-6]})

entropy(df)
>>> array([1.01140426,       -inf])

entropy(df[:2])
>>> array([0.63651417, 0.68696158])
```

Comment: Yes, my df contains negative numbers. Any suggestions on how to calculate entropy with these types of datasets with negative numbers?

Comment: The entropy is defined as `S = -sum(pk * log(pk), axis=0)` where pk defines the (discrete) distribution. pk[i] is the (possibly unnormalized) probability of event i. The log of negative numbers is not defined.